# How do I resolve runtime error 53, File Not Found?

Tags: vb6

I've a project that I didn't write and am making modifications to it, but am getting Error 53, File Not Found.

If I run the project from within Visual Basic, there is no error, but when I compile the executable and run that, is when I see error 53.

Can someone tell me the best way to go about troubleshooting this? If the error was happening inside Visual Basic, then I could use debugging tools, but it's only occurring with the compiled executable, and I have no idea what file cannot be found.

I just went through the entire form (where I believe this error is happening) and added the application path to every `Open` command where a file is being called, but still receive error 53 when running the compiled executable.

**EDIT**:
I was able to locate the file that can't be found. I can see the file is in the project directory, but cannot be found after the executable is built. Is there a special way of opening, or referring to this file?

The offending line:

```
Open "default.txt" For Input as #1
```

Comment: Too less information. I would need a working glass globe to understand the error. I do not even know, which "VBA" you are using (Access? Excel? Word? PowerPoint? Outlook?)

Comment: Thank you, I changed VBA to Visual Basic. I thought they were the same

Comment: Apparently your code uses relative paths and relies on the current directory which is different between the project and the exe. Find where files are opened and make sure the path is better defined. Alternatively, grab [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and see which paths are accessed.

Comment: No, VBA is not the same as VB6 (ok, the language is quite similar). So you tell us, you are working on a VB6 project. I assume, you have a working VB6 Installation. What happens, when you debug the program? (Set a break point and run from within the IDE)

Comment: You may consider implementing some form of error handling perhaps?

Comment: @GSerg,Thank you, GSerg. I downloaded procmon and will see what I can find.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor, Thanks for explaining that. It just proves that I don't anything at all about VB. :)  If I set debug mode, I can travel all the way through the program and nothing complains. It's only after I build the executable that I get this error.

Comment: @GSerg, "Procmon is not a valid win32 application" arg..

Comment: A quick and dirty approach:  use a message box to display the path and file names.

Comment: @BrianMStafford, Thanks, Brian, I'll try that. I was only able to find 3 references to `Open`, so it shouldn't be that bad. I'll post back here shortly

Comment: @BrianMStafford, Brian, thank you! I was able to pinpoint where it was coming from. The last developer wanted to open a file, so he just uses `Open "hisfile.txt" For Input #1`. That file is sitting in the project directory, so I know it's there. Why wouldn't that file be found?

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was to preface the file with `App.Path`.

My issue was that I had re-named my project directory, but my code did not reflect that change:

`App.Path & "\DirIForgotToIncludeHere\default.txt" For Input As #1`